# MS Access Join Queries without common field

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have an MS Access database that is used for monitoring my investment portfolio.

I have a series of individual queries which monitor individual stock performance on 1 Week, 1 Month, 3 Month, 6 Month interval etc and returns the top 5 values. What I want to now do is merge these into a table in a format similar to the following. What Tickers are shown for each period aren't necessary the same or the same order

Ticker1 - Gain1Week | Ticker2 - Gain1Month | Ticker3 - Gain3Month | Ticker4 - Gain6Month
Top Reading for wk    Top Reading for Mth    etc.
2nd Top Reading wk
etc.

Here is a sample of the individual query for Ticker2 - Gain 1Month

```
SELECT TOP 5 qryStockOverview01Month.StockID, Round(([CurrentPrice]-[1Month])/[1Month]*100,2) AS Gain01Month
FROM qryStockOverview01Month LEFT JOIN qryStockOverviewNow ON qryStockOverview01Month.StockID = qryStockOverviewNow.StockID
ORDER BY Round(([CurrentPrice]-[1Month])/[1Month]*100,2) DESC;
```

What I am unsure of is how to join the queries together given there is no common field. I did try to put a autonumber field in the query for 1 - 5 and was thinking could use that as the common field but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Your 'format' example doesn't make sense. Post sample raw data and desired output as text tables. Perhaps you need a UNION query or build a report with subreports.

Comment: Eahhh.. don't do it. In Access it'll be hideous (having to join each query to a sub query of itself on a.Gain01Month < b.Gain01Month, then grouping and counting that to realize a rownumber, then doing it again N times, then joining all these separate queries together on the rownumber..

Comment: Upgrade your DB to something decent (you can still access a sqlserver db from a Access front end) so you can just use ROW_NUMBER OVER and it doesn't drive you mental

Comment: The desired output is similar to this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/XLQM3un The backend of this database is on a mysql server if it makes a difference and just using access as the front end, queries and lookup tables. I did look at union queries but they dont add extra columns (at least it seems). As such maybe doing a report for each period and then butting the reports together as sub reports on another report is the solution (as messy as that is going to be). Thoughts?

Comment: If you want the data in descending order for each period, then build subreports. Or use the Row_Number suggestion - one query would have to serve as 'master' for the others to join to.

Comment: Have started to set up the sub report with extra subreports inside it. Been fiddly to get it all in line without gaps but for 3 periods so far it looks like it will work "ok". Will try set the others up tomorrow and see how it then looks I am still contemplating another solution that I have since thought of and that is to write a table via vba before the report opens however as much as this is cleaner feel it will probably also slow it up more by the multiple actions required and the report already takes a while to load up.

Comment: The Sub Reports method works ok. Still not entirely happy with it and may go the vba option in the future but it works for the moment and will plan to refine it later. Thanks all for your help